# behavior subject usage for shared services

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

shared-service.ts

```
intialValue: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

setInitialValue(value: any){
  this.intialValue.next(value)
}
```

app.component.ts

```
async ngOnInit(){
  //api call
  await this.sharedService.setInitialValue('api return value')
}
```

I do have home component in which by opening `localhost:4200/home` then refreshing it. I believe `app.component.ts` get called and api returns a value before `ngOnInit` in `home.component.ts` get called.

home.component.ts

```
ngOnInt(){
  this.sharedService.intialValue.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res) //it should be 'api return value' which is set in app.component but it showing null.
  });
}
```

What I observed is `home.component.ts`'s `ngOnInit` get called before `api success` call completion. How can I over come this scenario, am I using behaviourSubject and angular components, javascript synchronisation in wrong way?

Comment: If I've undertstand what you wrote, just change `BehaviorSubject` in `Subject` -> intialValue = new Subject<string>();

Comment: subject need to subscribe first before using that value.  so on normal `home.component.ts` load `ngOnInit` get called but  `intialValue` not `emitting` any value(on first subscribe).and by using subject I can achieve on refresh the component as you said but on normal load it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter initial value,

```
ngOnInt(){
  this.sharedService.intialValue
  .pipe(filter(v=>v))
  .subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res) 
  });
}
```

Comment: purpose of filter ?

Comment: so do you really care about the order of method execution instead of event data, since you already used BehaviorSubject?

Comment: yes, order of execution is high priority. behaviour subject can be replaced but why I used is it stores previous value.